# Django: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am doing an entry-level project and I met this problem.
**urls.py of project**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='welcome.html'), name='welcome'),
    path('accounts/', include('login.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), # use auth app
    path('ride_sharing/', include('ride.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**urls.py of ride app**:

```
app_name = 'ride'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('requests/', views.view_requests, name='view_requests'),
    path('new-request/', views.request_new, name='request_new'),
    path('driver/', views.driver_home, name='driver_home'),
    path('new-share-request/', views.sharer_request_new, name='sharer_request_new'),
]
```

**views.py of ride app, just incomplete codes**:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request,'ride/home.html')


def view_requests(request):
    return render(request, 'ride/home.html')


def request_new(request):
    return render(request, 'ride/home.html')


def driver_home(request):
    return render(request, 'ride/home.html')


def sharer_request_new(request):
    return render(request, 'ride/home.html')
```

And **home.html**:

```
<!-- ride/templates/ride/home.html -->

{% extends 'ride/base.html' %}

{% block title %}HOmeeeeeeeeeee {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Hi {{ user.username }}
    <p><a href="{% url 'ride:view_requests'  %}">View My Requests</a></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'ride:request_new' %}">Request a Ride</a></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'ride:driver_home' %}">Driver Entrance</a></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'ride:sharer_request_new' %}"></a></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></p>
{% else %}
  <p>Welcome to CJ & XY's Ride Sharing Service!</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> |
  <a href="{% url 'login:signup' %}">signup</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

But after I login (I make LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'), I get:

```
NoReverseMatch at /ride_sharing/
Reverse for 'view_requests' not found. 'view_requests' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

How could this happen? Could some give me the key? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues with your URLs. First off when you include an app.urls file you should give it a namespace. This allows reverse to find the proper location of the urls.py file and makes your life easier. Your include URLs should look like.

```
path('ride_sharing/', include('ride.urls', namespace="ride")),
```

Second issue is that you did not provide the proper reverse for your `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "ride:home"`

Then you should be good to go.